# WordPress login problem

Tags: login, user-access

I have a rather strange problem with my membership created completely through code even if on WordPress.

Basically if I try to log in with a blocked URL for example:
https://example.com/example

...I am redirected to the login page.

So far so good.

But when I log in and enter in the membership it happens that then I can't reach the page:
https://example.com/example

Here is the code that I use on the "example" page to redirect the user to the login screen if he is not logged in:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  wp_safe_redirect( home_url() . '/login.php');
  exit;
}
```

I use this PHP code on the top of the page of each page that is part of the membership.

Should i add some code that removes the caches?

I've also test this function [wp_cache_flush()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_flush/) but didn't work.

If I couldn't explained me this is the table of contents that follow my users and that cause the problem:

1) The user search my membership with a blocked URL in membership as an example: https://example.com/profile.

2) The user is therefore comes rightly to the login page.

3) When user insert credentials and log in and try to go in profile page he can't reach that page and he is redirected to the home.

This shouldn't be happening since he entered membership properly.

And the stranger thing is that only the page used for reach the login page is not reachable.

A heartfelt thanks to anyone who will give me a hand.

Please, anyone can help me? :)

Comment: "I can no longer reach the page" - what does happen? You still get redirected? You remain on the page but it doesn't load? Do you get anything loading, anything in 'view source' or just blank? Are there any errors on the screen, or in the server logs?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Practically once I log in I can no longer reach the example page that I had used in the URL before logging in which led me to login.

Comment: Could it be a cookie problem?
Because every time this type of problem happens I have to close the page and log in directly from the /login.php page of my site.
It is not wp-login.php because I modified and overloaded it.

Comment: "I use this PHP code right at the top of the page" - where exactly, in a template, in a hook callback - what hook if so? And did you modify the core `wp-login.php` file? Also, what do you mean by "overloaded"?

Comment: Sorry for my English. Yes, I have load login.php instead of wp-login.php but this is relative. I want know how can work my code correctly.

Comment: I mean the code show in my post

Comment: I have updated my request. I hope this is more clear. Sorry again for my English.

Comment: Sorry, @MatteoFeduzi, I don't always come back to posts I commented to, so you should mention the person you're replying to (i.e. `@<username>`) so that they get notified of your replies. :) And if the login problem still persists, perhaps including the code in your `login.php` in the question, can help us help you more.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you for the tip. My login.php is a copy of the wp-login.php file with the addition of some text, but it is not this file that gives me the problem.

Comment: @SallyCJ The problem comes from the code I use on each page within the member area, that is, the one specified in the post.

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi, it could be a caching issue, so have you tried clearing your site caches or disabling caching plugin for a while? And as I already asked before, where exactly is the code - in a template, in the theme `functions.php` file, in a function? I know you said at the top of the page, but in the file itself, where exactly it's placed?

Comment: But actually, the `wp-login.php` file shouldn't be "copied".. there are hooks and functions you can use to create your own login page.

Comment: @SallyCJ various changes were needed on the file and I opted to make a copy and overload it with the file I created login.php.

Comment: @SallyCJ However returning to us the code that inserted in the post above is present at the top of each page that is part of my members area. This is because I decided to make every single page of my site with the code. So to block access to people who have not logged in on my membership I use that code.
Below is the normal HTML code as well as basic functions such as get_header (), etc ...

Comment: Instead of putting the code there, try using the `functions.php` file. And run the code in the `wp` hook so that you can (use `is_page()` to) check if the current page is your members-only page/area. E.g. `add_action( 'init', function () { if ( is_page( 'members' ) ) { /* your code here */ } } )` But please re-consider using hooks and the login/user -related functions to create the login page. Alternatively, use a plugin and just customize where necessary.